# Session persistence problem

Tags: php, debugging, session

I'm having a problem with getting sessions to persist, and having no luck searching, I need to ask.

I can access the contents of my session as expected when first set, but as soon as the page refreshes I lose everything and I don't see why. `session_start()` is set and I'm not unseting or destroying anything. I looked at PHP Info under sessions and everything looks ok (but my understanding of sessions is limited).

I'm running MAMP on OS 10.5, and the last time I used sessions they worked.

Comment: session.cookie_lifetime is set at 0. Does that sound right?

Comment: I am getting an empty array with print_r($_SESSION); And sessions are being saved to the tmp folder, just not being made available.

Comment: Resolved! I shifted the session_start right to the top of code. PHP is fun! Only had a comment block above it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are refreshing the page you may be creating a new session and/or overwriting the session variables. You should check if a session variable is already set before setting it.

Comment: as in put session_start in an if statement?

Comment: I dont think session_start needs to be, but any session vars you are setting need to be.

Answer (score 1):

as Josh has said, you'll want to check for the sessions existence first before you start making a new one, use an if statement to check for the $_SESSION variable, that should give you the results you want. a lil debugging trick i use is to do this:

```
if($_SESSION) {
   echo 'session exists';
else {
   echo 'does not exist';
}
```

This way i know instantly what code block is being called, without worrying about whats contained inside.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Cookies enabled? You can also pass the session_id via the request (url).